# openjdk8u build in Solaris 10: failed with error

Tags: java, java-8, solaris-10, solaris-studio

When am building latest code from http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u, am getting some errors in solaris 10.
Following steps from: https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/raw-file/tip/README-builds.html

I was successfully able to build jdk8 in the same system. But when building jdk8u, facing some issues:
Configure:

```
 ./configure --with-tools-dir=/opt/solarisstudio12.4/bin/ --enable-jfr=yes --with-target-bits=32
```

bash-3.2# uname -a
SunOS FFPSNetSec 5.10 Generic_148889-05 i86pc i386 i86pc

/etc/release:

```
Oracle Solaris 10 8/11 s10x_u10wos_17b X86
  Copyright (c) 1983, 2011, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.
                            Assembled 23 August 2011
```

Error:

```
ld: warning: mapfile: text segment: section '.text%ntohl' does not appear in mapfile specified input file(s)
ld: warning: mapfile: text segment: section '.text%_init' does not appear in any input file
ld: warning: mapfile: text segment: section '.text%init64IO' does not appear in mapfile specified input file(s)
ld: warning: mapfile: text segment: section '.text%setPathEnvironment' does not appear in mapfile specified input file(s)
ld: warning: mapfile: text segment: section '.text%Java_java_io_FileSystem_getFileSystem' does not appear in any input file
ld: warning: mapfile: text segment: section '.text%Java_java_io_UnixFileSystem_canonicalize' does not appear in any input file
ld: warning: mapfile: text segment: section '.text%Java_java_lang_ClassLoader_findLoadedClass' does not appear in any input file
ld: warning: mapfile: text segment: section '.text%Java_java_lang_Float_floatToIntBits' does not appear in any input file
ld: warning: mapfile: text segment: section '.text%Java_java_lang_Double_doubleToLongBits' does not appear in any input file
ld: warning: mapfile: text segment: section '.text%Java_java_lang_Shutdown_halt' does not appear in any input file
ld: warning: mapfile: text segment: section '.text%Java_java_util_logging_FileHandler_lockFile' does not appear in any input file
ld: warning: mapfile: text segment: section '.text%Java_java_util_logging_FileHandler_unlockFile' does not appear in any input file
ld: warning: mapfile: text segment: section '.text%readLOC' does not appear in mapfile specified input file(s)
ld: warning: mapfile: text segment: section '.text%huft_build' does not appear in mapfile specified input file(s)
Undefined                       first referenced
 symbol                             in file
_IO_stdin_used                      /export/home/preethi/openjdk8u/jdk/make/mapfiles/launchers/mapfile-x86
__xargv                             /opt/solarisstudio12.4/lib/compilers/crt1x.o  (symbol has no version assigned)
__xargc                             /opt/solarisstudio12.4/lib/compilers/crt1x.o  (symbol has no version assigned)
ld: fatal: symbol referencing errors. No output written to /export/home/preethi/openjdk8u/build/solaris-x86-normal-server-release/jdk/objs/java_objs/java
gmake[2]: *** [/export/home/preethi/openjdk8u/build/solaris-x86-normal-server-release/jdk/objs/java_objs/java] Error 2
gmake[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
gmake[1]: *** [launchers-only] Error 2
gmake: *** [jdk-only] Error 2
```

I tried the same jdk8u source from openjdk and built --with-target-bits=64, build is completed without any error. But am not sure why it is failing for 32-bit.
Can anyone help me address this issue?

Answer (score 0):

32-bit builds of Java 8 on Solaris are not supported.

See [**Oracle JDK 8 and JRE 8 Certified System Configurations**](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/products-doc-jdk8-jre8-certconfig.html):